# I unparented a character model from a rig and modified it- Is it possible to easily parent it again?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

Recently, I was modifying an existing character, so I unparented it from its old rig and modified the mesh. I also made a new rig for the character, if that helps. However, this old rig has an animation that I want on the new version of the character. How would I go about bringing this old animation to this new character? Any solution would help.

The new rig and old rig are extremely different, so transferring the animation data doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hello, give the same name to the bones of the second armature, give it the same action as the first armature and see how it works?

Comment: The first armature is insanely complex compared to the first one, I don't think that's possible.